# Access shiny environment from exported functions

Tags: r, shiny

It seems exported functions in the R/ directory in an R package don't have access to variables, data.frames, etc. defined in the environment created by shinyServer. I could assign the variables, data.frames, etc. to the global environment but would like to avoid that.

shinyServer also generates a new/random name for the environment it uses. A key list/reactiveValues in my app is called `values` so a work-around I stumbled on is to use `env_shiny <<- pryr::where("values")` to determine where `values` lives.

In the exported functions from the R/ directory I can then `get("values", envir = env_shiny)[[dataset]]` to access the data I need.

I am wondering if there is a simpler/cleaner way to do this.