# Avoiding copies by using environments

Tags: r, shiny, bioconductor

In Hadley's Advanced R book there is section about using environments as a 'vessel for large objects' (see exert below). I'm looking for some examples that illustrate best practices for this approach. I looked [here](http://master.bioconductor.org/developers/) but didn't find anything that explicitly addressed this question.

In case it is relevant, my application is a shiny app where data in the app environment is shared with exported functions (in R/). See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28147302/access-shiny-environment-from-exported-functions).

The function used to manage data flow is [here](https://github.com/mostly-harmless/radiant/blob/master/R/radiant.R#L66-L85). `r_env` is the shiny environment. If analysis functions are called outside of the app the function looks for data dumped to R(studio) when the user quits the app or in the global environment.

http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html#explicit-envs

"**Avoiding copies**
Since environments have reference semantics, you’ll never accidentally create a copy. This makes it a useful vessel for large objects. It’s a common technique for bioconductor packages which often have to manage large genomic objects. "

**EDIT**

I would expect differences based on how data is passed to functions. Using a few different approaches the differences appear to be minimal. What is different in the approach used in the (unnamed) bioconductor packages Hadley is referring to?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(microbenchmark)
dat <- diamonds
dataset <- "dat"
r_env <- new.env()
r_env$dat <- diamonds

reg1 <- function(dataset) 
    lm(price ~ carat + color, data = get(dataset))

reg2 <- function(dataset) 
    lm(price ~ carat + color, data = r_env[[dataset]])

reg3 <- function(dat) 
    lm(price ~ carat + color, data = dat)

microbenchmark(times = 100,
  reg1(dataset),
  reg2(dataset),
  reg3(dat)
)

Unit: milliseconds
          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 reg1(dataset) 75.52479 85.50742 87.80560 87.57180 89.59216 96.34956   100
 reg2(dataset) 83.98896 85.51443 87.40334 87.00544 88.84889 94.01787   100
     reg3(dat) 61.00551 86.01789 88.15627 88.13501 90.48899 95.05454   100
```

Comment: The second half of the paragraph about avoiding copies is: "Changes to R 3.1.0 have made this use substantially less important because modifying a list no longer makes a deep copy. Previously, modifying a single element of a list would cause every element to be copied, an expensive operation if some elements are large. Now, modifying a list efficiently reuses existing vectors, saving much time."

Comment: Do lists have reference semantics? Would passing lists to functions for analysis be as efficient as passing a reference? If so, it would be great to see an example.

Comment: If you want to learn about R and performance, I highly recommend [this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/) open source book, specifically the sections on [performance](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Performance.html) and [memory](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#memory)

Answer (score 3):

For reference semantics of lists and functions, here's a function that modifies a list element

```
f = function (l) {
    l[[1]][1] = 2
    l
}
```

Here's a list and it's internal representation before and after the function applied to it

```
> l = list(a=1:5, b=1:5)
> .Internal(inspect(l))
@b3baa80 19 VECSXP g0c2 [NAM(1),ATT] (len=2, tl=0)
  @a4133a8 13 INTSXP g0c3 [] (len=5, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5
  @a4133f0 13 INTSXP g0c3 [] (len=5, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5
ATTRIB:
  @894b670 02 LISTSXP g0c0 [] 
    TAG: @1406d18 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,NAM(2),LCK,gp=0x6000] "names" (has value)
    @b3baab8 16 STRSXP g0c2 [] (len=2, tl=0)
      @15c8f68 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "a"
      @17f47e8 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "b"
> .Internal(inspect(f(l)))
@b2da518 19 VECSXP g0c2 [NAM(1),ATT] (len=2, tl=0)
  @6d6b3f0 14 REALSXP g0c4 [] (len=5, tl=0) 2,2,3,4,5
  @a4133f0 13 INTSXP g0c3 [NAM(2)] (len=5, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5
ATTRIB:
  @85031c8 02 LISTSXP g0c0 [] 
    TAG: @1406d18 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,NAM(2),LCK,gp=0x6000] "names" (has value)
    @b3baab8 16 STRSXP g0c2 [NAM(2)] (len=2, tl=0)
      @15c8f68 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "a"
      @17f47e8 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "b"
```

Before the function call, this part

```
@b3baa80 19 VECSXP g0c2 [NAM(1),ATT] (len=2, tl=0)
  @a4133a8 13 INTSXP g0c3 [] (len=5, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5
  @a4133f0 13 INTSXP g0c3 [] (len=5, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5
```

is the list (VECSXP) and to integer vectors (INTSXP). The @ are the memory addresses of the data. After the function call we have

```
@b2da518 19 VECSXP g0c2 [NAM(1),ATT] (len=2, tl=0)
  @6d6b3f0 14 REALSXP g0c4 [] (len=5, tl=0) 2,2,3,4,5
  @a4133f0 13 INTSXP g0c3 [NAM(2)] (len=5, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5
```

The address of the overall list and of the modified element have changed, but importantly the address of the second element has not.

One would see similar behavior with an environment, except that the overall SXP would not have changed. Also of course one would introduce reference semantics (the original environment would be changed, even if the return value of the function call were returned to a different symbol), which is probably very undesirable.